# Problema conexion modulo

Tags: javascript, websocket

Estoy modificando un modulo de node red para ajustarlo a una necesidad que tengo.
(el modulo esta aqui https://github.com/Argonne-National-Laboratory/node-red-contrib-ocpp/blob/master/ocpp/ocpp-cp-json.js)
El modulo, consiste en realizar una conexion a sobre un servidor para intercambia unos datos.

EL problema que tengo, es que si se conecta, aparece como "conectado", y aunque se corte internet aparece como conectado constantemente(en ocasiones si pasa mucho rato detecta que no hay internet). Si se inicia sin conexion, aunque luego tenga internet, no intenta realizar la conexion.

Pego el codigo

```js
const Websocket = require('ws');
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
const events = require('events');
const EventEmitter = events.EventEmitter;
const Logger = require('./utils/logdata');
const debug = require('debug')('anl:ocpp:cp:server:json');

let ee = new EventEmitter();

module.exports = function(RED) {
  function OCPPChargePointJNode(config) {
    RED.nodes.createNode(this, config);
                            
    debug('Starting CP client JSON node');
    const CALL = 2;
    const CALLRESULT = 3;

    // for logging...
    const msgTypeStr = ['unknown', 'unknown', 'received', 'replied', 'error'];

    const msgType = 0;
    const msgId = 1;
    const msgAction = 2;
    const msgCallPayload = 3;
    const msgResPayload = 2;
    var obj = require('./global.json'); 
    var node = this;

    node.reqKV = {};

    this.remotecs = RED.nodes.getNode(config.remotecs);
    this.url = obj.url;
    this.cbId = obj.cbId;
    this.ocppVer = this.ocppver;
    this.name = obj.nombre || config.name || this.remotecs.name;
    this.command = config.command;
    this.cmddata = config.cmddata;
    this.logging = config.log || false;
    this.pathlog = config.pathlog;


    const logger = new Logger(this, this.pathlog, this.name);
    logger.enabled = (this.logging && (typeof this.pathlog === 'string') && this.pathlog !== '');

    let csUrl = `${this.url}/${this.cbId}`;

    logger.log('info', `Realizando conexion websocket a ${csUrl}`);

    let ws = new Websocket(csUrl, {handshaketimeout: 5000});

    ws.on('open', function(){
      node.status({fill: 'green', shape: 'dot', text: 'Conectado...'});
      node.wsconnected = true;
    });
    ws.on('close', function(){
      logger.log('info', `Closing websocket connectio to ${csUrl}`);
      node.status({fill: 'red', shape: 'dot', text: 'Cerrado...'});
      node.wsconnected = false;

    });

    ws.on('error', function(err){
      node.log(`Websocket error: ${err}`);
      debug(`Websocket error: ${err}`);
    });

    ws.on('message', function(msgIn) {
      debug('Got a message ');
      let msg = {};
      msg.ocpp = {};
      msg.payload = {};

      msg.ocpp.ocppVersion = '1.6j';

      let response = [];
      let id = uuidv4();

      let msgParsed;


      if (msgIn[0] != '[') {
        msgParsed = JSON.parse('[' + msgIn + ']');
      } else {
        msgParsed = JSON.parse(msgIn);
      }

      logger.log(msgTypeStr[msgParsed[msgType]], JSON.stringify(msgParsed));

      if (msgParsed[msgType] == CALL) {
        debug(`Got a CALL Message ${msgParsed[msgId]}`);
        // msg.msgId = msgParsed[msgId];
        msg.msgId = id;
        msg.ocpp.MessageId = msgParsed[msgId];
        msg.ocpp.msgType = CALL;
        msg.ocpp.command = msgParsed[msgAction];
        msg.payload.command = msgParsed[msgAction];
        msg.payload.data = msgParsed[msgCallPayload];

        let to = setTimeout(function(id) {
          // node.log("kill:" + id);
          if (ee.listenerCount(id) > 0) {
            let evList = ee.listeners(id);
            let x = evList[0];
            ee.removeListener(id, x);
          }
        }, 120 * 1000, id);

        // This makes the response async so that we pass the responsibility onto the response node
        ee.once(id, function(returnMsg) {
          clearTimeout(to);
          response[msgType] = CALLRESULT;
          response[msgId] = msgParsed[msgId];
          response[msgResPayload] = returnMsg;

          logger.log(msgTypeStr[response[msgType]], JSON.stringify(response).replace(/,/g, ', '));

          ws.send(JSON.stringify(response));

        });
        node.status({fill: 'green', shape: 'dot', text: `message in: ${msg.ocpp.command}`});
        debug(`${ws.url} : message in: ${msg.ocpp.command}`);
        node.send(msg);
      } else if (msgParsed[msgType] == CALLRESULT) {
        debug(`Got a CALLRESULT msgId ${msgParsed[msgId]}`);
        msg.msgId = msgParsed[msgId];
        msg.ocpp.MessageId = msgParsed[msgId];
        msg.ocpp.msgType = CALLRESULT;
        msg.payload.data = msgParsed[msgResPayload];

        if (node.reqKV.hasOwnProperty(msg.msgId)){
          msg.ocpp.command = node.reqKV[msg.msgId];
          delete node.reqKV[msg.msgId];
        } else {
          msg.ocpp.command = 'unknown';
        }

        node.status({fill: 'green', shape: 'dot', text: `response in: ${msg.ocpp.command}`});
        debug(`response in: ${msg.ocpp.command}`);
        node.send(msg);

      }

    });

    ws.on('ping', function(){
      debug('Got Ping');
      ws.send('pong');
    });
    ws.on('pong', function(){
      debug('Got Pong');
    });
    ws.on('close', function(code,reason){
      debug(`Cerrado websocket CP cliente, codigo: ${code}, razón: ${reason}`);
    });

    this.on('input', function(msg) {

      if (node.wsconnected == true){

        let request = [];
        let messageTypeStr = ['unknown', 'unknown', 'request', 'replied', 'error'];

        debug(JSON.stringify(msg));

        request[msgType] = msg.payload.msgType || CALL;
        request[msgId] = msg.payload.MessageId || uuidv4();

        if (request[msgType] == CALL){
          request[msgAction] = msg.payload.command || node.command;

          if (!request[msgAction]){
            const errStr = 'ERROR: Missing Command in JSON request message';
            node.error(errStr);
            debug(errStr);
            return;
          }


          let cmddata;
          if (node.cmddata){
            try {
              cmddata = JSON.parse(node.cmddata);
            } catch (e){
              node.warn('OCPP JSON client node invalid payload.data for message (' + msg.ocpp.command + '): ' + e.message);
              return;
            }

          }

          request[msgCallPayload] = msg.payload.data || cmddata || {};
          if (!request[msgCallPayload]){
            const errStr = 'ERROR: Missing Data in JSON request message';
            node.error(errStr);
            debug(errStr);
            return;
          }

          node.reqKV[request[msgId]] = request[msgAction];
          debug(`Sending message: ${request[msgAction]}, ${request}`);
          node.status({fill: 'green', shape: 'dot', text: `request out: ${request[msgAction]}`});
        } else {
          request[msgResPayload] = msg.payload.data || {};
          debug(`Sending response message: ${JSON.stringify(request[msgResPayload])}`);
          node.status({fill: 'green', shape: 'dot', text: 'sending response'});
        }
        
        logger.log(messageTypeStr[request[msgType]], JSON.stringify(request).replace(/,/g, ', '));

        ws.send(JSON.stringify(request));
      }
    });

    this.on('close', function(){
      node.status({fill: 'red', shape: 'dot', text: 'Closed...'});
      logger.log('info', 'Websocket closed');
      debug('Closing CP client JSON node..');
      //ws.close();
    });

  }
  // register our node
  RED.nodes.registerType('CP client JSON', OCPPChargePointJNode);
};
```

Lo que me gustaria añadir al codigo, es que compruebe cada x segundos si esta conectado y en caso negativo, que empieze el proceso de nuevo para intentar conectarse.

Soy un poco novato en esto, he intentado varias cosas sin resultado...

Gracias a todos por la ayuda!

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizar un *cron job*. Una tarea que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo.
Para ello, se suele usar un [`setInterval`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args)

```
setInterval(() => {
  if (! node.wsconnected)
    tryConnect();
}, POLL_CONNECTION);
```

Donde `POLL_CONNECTION` es el número de milisegundos que querrás ir comprobando la conexión. Te puedo proponer que vaya estrechamente ligado con el *timeout* de los *ACK* de la conexión (los `5000` de `handshaketimeout`).

`tryConnect` es un método que va a reintentar de nuevo la conexión, en caso que esté caída.
Además, podrías obtener el `Timer` que devuelve `setInterval` para cancelarlo en caso de no querer hacer más este *polling* (en el evento `close`, por ejemplo).

```
const reconnection = setInterval(() => {
  if (! node.wsconnected)
    tryConnect();
}, POLL_CONNECTION);

//  ...

ws.on('close', function() {
  // ...
  clearInterval(reconnection);
});
```

Adicionalmente, aunque no tenga mucho que ver con la pregunta, me gustaría mencionar que deberías separar tu código en varias funciones (y ficheros, también) con tal de tener mayor facilidad de desarrollo, lectura y escalabilidad.

```
// common.js ...
module.exports = {
    CALL: 2,
    CALLRESULT: 3,
    msgTypeStr: ['unknown', 'unknown', 'received', 'replied', 'error'],
    msgType: 0,
    msgAction: 2,
    msgCallPayload: 3,
    msgRedPayload: 2
};
```

```
// events.js ...
module.exports = {

    onOpen: node => {
        node.status({fill: 'green', shape: 'dot', text: 'Conectado...'});
        node.wsconnected = true;
    },

    onClose: node => {
        // ...
    },

    // ...

};
```

```
// main.js ...
const common = require('./common');
const events = require('./events');
const { onOpen, onClose } = events;

// ...
ws.on('open', () => onOpen(node));
ws.on('close', () => onclose(node));
```

Obviamente se podrían hacer muchos tipos de abstracciones según las necesidades. Por ejemplo, hacer un wrap de los eventos con un mismo `node` para no tener que pasarlo como argumento en cada evento, etc... Pero es una idea.

Espero que sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias @VRoxa por tu ayuda.

He probado lo que me propones pero me da error .
este es el codigo añadido con los ms en el POLL_CONNECTION

```js
const reconnection = setInterval(() => {
  if (! node.wsconnected)
    tryConnect();
}, 5000);
ws.on('close', function() {
  clearInterval(reconnection);
});
```

y el error que me devuelve es:

ReferenceError: tryConnect is not defined

Seguramente estaré realizando algo mal, soy muy novato...

Gracias y saludos!

Comment: he cambiado     tryConnect(); por     tryConnection(); y no me sale el fallo, pero tampoco me reconecta estando desconectado.